# how to overlap contents of iframe tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made this search bar... And i want to use this page on many pages using iframe tag.
But when i use it and when results  are shown, it shifts other elements, or a scroll bar is visible ... I want the result to overlaped on the other contents of the site... So that it is visible normally...
here is my code---

```
function filterFunction() {
    let isInputAvail = false;
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
    if (filter.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.add("show");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.remove("show");
    }
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        txtValue = a[i].innerText;
        if (txtValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            isInputAvail = true;
            a[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    if (!isInputAvail) {
        document.getElementById("noMatches").classList.add('show');
    } else {
        document.getElementById("noMatches").classList.remove('show');
    }
}
```

```
.div {
    display: none;
}

.dropbtn {
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

#myInput {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-position: 14px 12px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
    border: 5px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

#myInput:focus {
    outline: 4px solid #f2f2f2;
    border-color: #171313;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    max-height: 215px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    min-width: 230px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: none;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```
<div class="dropdown">
      <input type="text" class="dropbtn"  placeholder="Search Here..." id="myInput" onInput="filterFunction()">
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
             <a href="#">Result 1</a>
        <a href="#">Result 2</a>
        <a href="#">Result 3</a>
        <a href="#">Result 4</a>
        <a href="#">Result 5</a>
        <a href="#">Result 6</a>
        <a href="#">Result 7</a>
        <a href="#">Result 8</a>
        <a href="#">Result 9</a>
        <a href="#">Result 10</a>
        <a href="#">Result 11</a>
        <a href="#">Result 12</a>
        <a href="#">Result 13</a>
        <a href="#">Result 14</a>
        <a href="#">Result 15</a>
      </div>
      <div id="noMatches" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#tools">No Matches</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can't have elements overflow outside an iframe if that is what you are asking

Comment: Yes you got my point... Can't the whole iframe tag me overlap on the contents. I just want it not to disturb the other contents...

Comment: With absolute positioning it can yes

Comment: pls explain....

Comment: https://ibb.co/hfpM4vM   You can see this image to better understand the issue.. the dropdown get hidden below the banner image.. i  want it to be shown over it without shifting the other contents.

Comment: That is a css z-index issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220647/discussion-between-harshit-mishra-and-charlietfl).

Comment: can you explaine it more briefly??? or show me the code or any example?

Answer (score 1):

I still don't get was this what you meant.

```
<style>
.dropbtn{
padding: 16px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 25px;
}

#myInput{
box-sizing: border-box;
background-position: 14px 12px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
border: 5px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 25px;
}

#myInput:focus{
outline: 4px solid #f2f2f2;
border-color: #171313;
}

.dropdown{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: flex-start;
}

.dropdown-content{
max-height: 215px;
display: none;
top: 60px;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f6f6f6;
min-width: 230px;
max-width: 70px;
overflow-y: scroll;
border: none;
z-index: 1;
border-radius: 25px;
}

.dropdown-content a{
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover{background-color: #ddd;}

.show{display: block;}

body{margin: 0;}
.header{
height: 90px;width: 100vw;
display: flex;position: relative;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-around;
z-index: 10;
}
.dropdown-content::-webkit-scrollbar{
background: transparent;
width: 0;
display: none;
}

.banner{
background-color: #AAA;color: white;
height: 150px;width: 100vw;
top: 90px;left: 0;
display: block;position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
}
</style>



<div class="header">
<div class="dropdown">
<input type="text" class="dropbtn"placeholder="Search Here..." id="myInput" onInput="filterFunction()"/>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Result 1 a very long long line one result</a>
<a href="#">Result 2</a>
<a href="#">Result 3</a>
<a href="#">Result 4</a>
<a href="#">Result 5</a>
<a href="#">Result 6</a>
<a href="#">Result 7</a>
<a href="#">Result 8</a>
<a href="#">Result 9</a>
<a href="#">Result 10</a>
<a href="#">Result 11</a>
<a href="#">Result 12</a>
<a href="#">Result 13</a>
<a href="#">Result 14</a>
<a href="#">Result 15</a>
</div>
<div id="noMatches" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#tools">No Matches</a>
</div>
</div>
<div>Other</div>
</div>
<div class="banner">Banner Content<div>
```

Comment: i have found an alternative and fixed my problem by another method.... By the way thank  for giving your time and helping me... thanks a lot bro.....  and i will also try this if it would work i will write here....

Answer (score 0):

Don't get it but is it something like top: 60px;left: 0; in .dropdown-content?

Comment: i want to use an page on many of other pages using iframe(or any other method if possible). On using iframe it shifts the contents below it. So i just want that the drop overlaps on the contents so that the content is at its place and dropdown can be seen over it..... Hope you understand...

Comment: you can see this image for better understanding... the dropdown is hiding at the backside of the banner image  ...............      ------------- https://ibb.co/hfpM4vM

Comment: Nice smartphone that it gets mispresented as korean like oppa. I thought {display: fixed;z-index: 9999;} could not repositioning other content.

Comment: Well, it seems as very fundamental ancient problem from earlier world wide web, that you have to be patient to achieving or passing good in Life—cough—which is a bundle of problems; where many people and party or entity mind their own goals and many other do really love to posing as a trial. Had you tried it? It seems as the CSS.

Comment: can you explaine it more briefly??? or show me the code or any example?

Comment: I tried your code, and i didn’t found this repositioning or height change. I can't put that in this comment box. Maybe it's different browser; diffferent browser has different settings. The use of <iframe> had also get banned in many sites since it may mimic false placement like for passwords.

Comment: oh .. thanks for the effort bro... By the way i have found an alternate way for my problem and used another method for it... Thanks a lot for the help......

Comment: And what was that so i can also understand your question?